# When I try to type something, the screen keyboard always appears. How can I make it not appear?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

When there's a text imput ticker on the screen (such as when using telegram or firefox) the touchscreen keyboard **always** appears. So I have to close it over and over again.

It started to happen when I installed the On screen keyboard button extension from GNOME Shell Extensions and I have tried to unistall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall `On Screen keyboard button` by either...

- Start `Tweak Tool`, click `Extensions` in the left pane, find `On Screen keyboard button` and click `Remove`.

[image]

- Go to http://extensions.gnome.org, click on `Installed Extensions`, locate `On Screen keyboard button`, then click the RED X icon.

[image]

Now, to disable the On Screen keyboard, open System Settings, select `Universal Access`, and turn off the `Screen Keyboard`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about Universal Access thing.